# VS Code Just Won't Debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

This is driving me bananas.  VS Code version is 1.24.1.

tsconfig.app.json looks like this:

```
    {
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "sourceMap":true,
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

launch.json looks like this:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 4200
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMaps":true
        }
    ]
}
```

Customized user settings:

```
{
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true,
    "debug.enableAllHovers": true,
    "debug.inlineValues": true,
}
```

This is a simple angular 6 application.

Not one breakpoint will hit while in VS Code.  Nothing.  What am I missing here.  This literally worked days ago, only environmental difference on the machine is newly installed VS 2017 Professional.  Otherwise, there are no differences.